# can't run the google map feature in android

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to use the google maps feature in android. I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview. But when I run the app, there seems to be some kind of problem. I'm not sure what it is but the app won't load.
Here is the errors listed in the logcat.

```
07-26 02:01:01.771: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(158): ERROR: thread attach failed

07-26 02:01:06.761: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(211): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

07-26 02:01:06.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.trainingcenter.maps/com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43b7d958

07-26 02:01:06.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(211): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43b7d958

07-26 02:01:06.931: ERROR/dalvikvm(211): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

07-26 02:01:17.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242): ERROR: thread attach failed

07-26 02:01:26.391: ERROR/ActivityThread(63): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

07-26 02:02:24.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323): ERROR: thread attach failed

07-26 02:07:12.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(417): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

07-26 02:07:12.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.trainingcenter.maps/com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02ee8

07-26 02:07:12.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(417): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trainingcenter.maps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02ee8
```

Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks for the help.

Here is the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.trainingcenter.maps" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here is the activity

```
package com.trainingcenter.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Here's the main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true" 
    android:apiKey="I inserted the API key here, I got it from http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html" />
```

Btw, I'm using Google API level 2.1 update 1

Comment: Did you add the activity to your manifest?

Comment: I just copied the code in the link I give. I'll edit the question to include the code and manifest

Comment: Now let's see your xml, did you give it a map API key?

Comment: I added the xml part. I included the API key in the MapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` Needs to be within the `<application>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trainingcenter.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**Edit:**

In your xml file, i'd also add the `android:enabled="true"`

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:apiKey="I inserted the API key here, I got it from http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: it worked. thank you. btw, with only that in my code. does the output only just a white screen with gridlines? or something is wrong?

Comment: You running on a device or in the Emulator? I believe people have had issues with not getting internet in the Emulator but I may be wrong. Check your API key next, that happened to me a long time ago. Did you make sure that you got the MD5 sum when registering your API key and not the SHA?

Comment: I'm running on an emulator. I'm not sure if I'm getting internet in the emulator, I'll try out the browser. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the SHA, when I generated my key using the keytool I got a Certificate fingerprint (MD5), I used that when I sign up for an API key

Comment: It turns out, I'm not getting internet connection from the emulator I'm using, I'll try with another and see if I can get any.

Comment: I tried with another emulator. There's an internet connection. I was able to browse the Internet but the output of the app is still the same

Comment: I saw that you missed a line in your xml file, check my edited answer and see if that helps.

Comment: I added the android:enabled="true" in the xml file. still the same output.

Comment: Okay, one last thing I think it could be. When developing you should use your debug certificate to get your API Key - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getdebugfingerprint. But remember when you sign your application you'll need to use your signing certificate - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint

Comment: I think I read in that guide that if you run the app in debug mode, a predefined certificate is used for signing the app. Thus this affect my app? since my API key is registered to my generated certificate, right?

Comment: Their docs do say "If your MapView objects reference an API Key that you obtained by registering the debug certificate, then you must sign your application with the debug certificate." Your API key is the debug key, correct? I can't think of any other reason you'd get the grid. I'd try going through the API Key instructions again for debug certificate and, hopefully, that works.

Comment: OR... Push the app to a device, if you have one and see if the `MapView` works...

Comment: I finally got it. I'm not using the debug key during my first try that's why I got the error. I switched to it and I got the result. Thank you for your help sir. Good day :)